# Python guessing game (need help getting closest number)

Tags: python

im trying to have 2 players, both guesses a number between 1-10. script generates a random number from 1-10 and both users guess and i need a algorithm that says which player was the closest to the guess

```
python
import random

x = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
w = random.choice(x)

close = user - 1
close2 = user + 2

while 1:
    user = raw_input('bet: ')

    if user == w:
        print('you won')
        break
    else:
        print 'you lost'
```

Comment: What problem / error do you get with your current code? Describe it, even if it seems obvious!

Comment: there's no problem with this code, i need some algorithm to find the closest between both players

Comment: What's wrong with the absolute value of the difference between the guessed values and the correct value?

Comment: i need the code to say which player was closest to the correct guess

Comment: please add the code for making sure that this code will allow only two turns and each guess is separately recorded, once you have that information, you should find the absolute difference for each guess and award the least different the prize.

Answer (score 2):

```
import random

value = random.choice(range(1,11))

distance = {}

for player in ['p1', 'p2']:
    distance[player] = abs(int(input(player + ' bet:')) - value)

print('Winner: {}'.format(min(distance, key=distance.get)))
```

This does not deal with players not inputing integers or draw games. I'll leave that to you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your code but the code below wait for an input of each player before comparing these values to the one picked by the computer

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 *-

from random import randrange
from math import fabs


user1Guess = input("User 1 bet :")
user2Guess = input("User 2 bet :")
user1Guess = int(user1Guess)
user2Guess = int(user2Guess)
computerGuess = randrange(1,11)
u1diff = fabs(computerGuess-user1Guess)
u2diff = fabs(computerGuess-user2Guess)

if u1diff == u2diff:
    print("Tie")
elif u1diff < u2diff:
    print("User 1 won")
else:
    print("User 2 won")
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below generates a random number between 1 and 10 and takes players' (users') inputs and compares. You missed the case where there's a draw

```py
x = random.randint(1,11)

bet1 = int(input('Enter bet for user 1:'))
bet2 = int(input('Enter bet for user 2:'))

if abs(x-bet1) < abs(x-bet2):
    print('user 1  wins')
elif abs(x-bet1) > abs(x-bet2) :
    print('user 2 wins')
else:
    print('draw')
```